# What is the best way to master algorithms?

Tags: algorithm, data-structures

I am a beginner, and can only solve a few questions (1-2) from the 5 question sets given by codeforces. I wanted to know if there is any website that makes you learn all the types of algo with stepwise difficulty and show you the best approach for each question too.

Comment: Stackoverflow is for practical programming problems you have faced. So, this question doesn't fit well here. BTW, most of the contests on codeforces have reviews and open discussion. You can also sort problems in archive by difficulty level and use solutions by top users to learn and practice.

Comment: I can recommend https://www.coursera.org/#course/algo . You can sign up for free and it is a great environment for step by step learning.

Comment: I recommend that for data-structure you should look at the book "Introduction to algorithm by Thomas H Cormen".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume that you are talking about learning java in data structures. There is a website I can refer you to practice some problems. The website is http://www.codingbat.com/ where you can learn data structures and algorithm practice in java and python. Good Luck!